# WPF MediaElement.IsLooping property not found?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

The MSDN Docs show a property for MediaElement named IsLooping, yet Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize it.

I have a custom MediaElement subclass and am able to access other properties in it (and it is in fact playing video) but code completion doesn't see IsLooping, nor does it compile when I use that property.

What am I missing?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.islooping.aspx

Comment: That looks like the documentation for the Windows XAML reference. You want the WPF documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is the Requirements section at the bottom of the page,

> Requirements (Windows 10 device family)
>
> Device family Universal, introduced version 10.0.10240.0
>
> API contract Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, introduced
>   version 1.0
>
> Namespace Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls [C++]
>
> Metadata Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
>
> Requirements (Windows 8.x and Windows Phone 8.x)
>
> Minimum supported client Windows 8
>
> Minimum supported server Windows Server 2012
>
> Minimum supported phone Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]
>
> Namespace Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls [C++]
>
> Metadata Windows.winmd

the documentation you are looking at is the UWP Media Element not the WPF media element, so can only me used when you are looking at the WinRT or UWP framework

the WPF documentation can be located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) and as you can see doesn't have a IsLooping property

Answer (score 0):

Media element in WPF doesnot support IsLooping you can use the below code instead

```
private void mediaElement_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    mediaElement.Play();
}
```